# Passing Swaps and Comparisons into quicksort function

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I'm making this program where I have to count the number of swaps and comparisons a quick sort function, and we have to pass the swaps and comps to the function. I'm not too sure how to do this. I have it so it can be done without passing anything to it, as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

struct SwapandComp {
    int swaps;
    int comps;
};

const long ARRAY_SIZE = 5000;
int totalSwaps = 0;
int totalComps = 0;

int partition(int[], int, int) //add parameters int& swap and int& comp
SwapandComp quickSort(int[], int, int) //also add parameters for int& swap and int& comp

int main() {

SwapandComp qui;
long masterAry[ARRAY_SIZE] = {0};
int quickAry[ARRAY_SIZE] = {0};
int start = 0;
int end = 0;
double difference = 0;
int size = ARRAY_SIZE;

srand(time(NULL));

for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
masterAry[i] = rand();
}

for (int a = 0; a < ARRAY_SIZE; a++) {
quickAry[a] = masterAry[a];
}

start = clock();
qui = quickSort(quickAry, 0, ARRAY_SIZE - 1);
    end = clock();
    difference = end - start;
    double f = difference / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    cout << "Quick: " << f << " " << qui.swaps << " " << qui.comps << endl;
}
```

This is the main. It's where values are assigned to the array to be sorted by the quickSort function, which will be defined below.

```
int partition(int numbers[], int i, int k) { //add parameters int& swap and int& comp
    int l = 0;
    int h = 0;
    int midpoint = 0;
    int pivot = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    bool done = false;

    // Pick middle element as pivot
    midpoint = i + (k - i) / 2;
    pivot = numbers[midpoint];

    l = i;
    h = k;

    while (!done) {

        // Increment l while numbers[l] < pivot
        while (numbers[l] < pivot) {
            ++l;
            totalComps++;
        }

        // Decrement h while pivot < numbers[h]
        while (pivot < numbers[h]) {
            --h;
            totalComps++;
        }

        // If there are zero or one elements remaining,
        // all numbers are partitioned. Return h
        if (l >= h) {
            totalComps++;
            done = true;
        }
        else {
            // Swap numbers[l] and numbers[h],
            // update l and h
            temp = numbers[l];
            numbers[l] = numbers[h];
            numbers[h] = temp;
            totalSwaps++;

            ++l;
            --h;
        }
    }

    //cout << totalSwaps << " " << totalComps << endl;
    return h;
}
```

This is the partition function to find where to find the next partition point

```
SwapandComp quickSort(int numbers[], int i, int k) { //add parameters int& swap and int& comp
    SwapandComp quick = { 0 };
    //quick.swaps = quick.comps = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int z = 0;


    // Base case: If there are 1 or zero elements to sort,
    // partition is already sorted
    if (i >= k) {
        return quick;
    }

    // Partition the data within the array. Value j returned
    // from partitioning is location of last element in low partition.
    j = partition(numbers, i, k);

    // Recursively sort low partition (i to j) and
    // high partition (j + 1 to k)
    quickSort(numbers, i, j);
    quickSort(numbers, j + 1, k);

    quick.swaps = totalSwaps;
    quick.comps = totalComps;



    //totalSwaps = 0;
    //totalComps = 0;

    return quick;
}
```

And finally, here is the quick sort function where all the swaps and comps will be added together and put into the struct. Again, I'm not too sure how to add in the pass by reference variables for swap and comp. Any help is appreciated! (Also sorry about the code formatting, it got kind of crazy on my screen.)

Comment: do you  know how to pass a parameter by reference in general? Or is there some specific problem in passing by reference in this code?

Comment: what happened when you tried what that comment says "//add parameters int& swap and int& comp" ?

Comment: @user463035818 When I tried putting it in the way I did into the functions, the swaps and comps outputted as `-8000000 -80000000` (around there)

Comment: its not easy to answer your question because thats quite a lot of code. If your sorting works and the question is only about the counting, then you could remove everything but the comparing and swapping. Or start with an example that doesnt compare or swap anything but only resembles the way you want to pass the counters and nothing else. It doesnt have to be more than a couple of lines of code. Sometimes its also better to show the code that does not work and the error message / the wrong output you get instead of code that is working. Also read about [mcve]